# How to check mat-checkbox based on label during Cypress test?

Tags: checkbox, angular-material, cypress

Is it possible to check a `mat-checkbox` in a Cypress test based on it's label text?

Below is the HTML for the checkbox:

[image]

I have several checkboxes to test, so I want to re-use code to do something like -
***When I check the 'Advanced search' checkbox***, ***When I check the 'Basic search' checkbox, etc.***

Comment: Please do not post images of code, instead post the actual code in text

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<mat-checkbox>` can be accessed by label text with a simple `.contains()`, but you must use `.click()` instead of `.check()`.

```js
cy.contains('mat-checkbox', 'Advanced search')
  .click()
```

Using `.check()` gives you the error

> `<input>` is being covered by another element `<label>`

Answer (score 1):

If the `label` only holds one check box for `Advanced search`, then you can use [`.contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains) with `label` as the selector along with text of the checkbox, then `.find()` the checkbox to check.

```js
// this will get label element
cy.contains('label', /advanced search/i)
  // this will get checkbox input
  .find('input[type=checkbox]')
  .check()
```

Here is a working [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/integration/findCheckboxByText.md).